# How to show modal after 3 seconds while allowing a change in checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html

I'm displaying tables with different policies that have severities such as

Once the page loads, as soon as the user clicks on a checkbox, I am just displayingin the empty table. Then I am waiting 3 seconds so that the user can change their checkbox selections if they'd like. If they click another box, then I start the 3-sec timer again. Once the 3 seconds are up, I display the modal saying

The issue is that if the user decides to change their selections within the 3 seconds, the timer doesn't reset. Because of that, once the data loads, it doesn't always display the most recent checkbox selection. Sometimes it displays the first change they made and then refreshes again after a while to display the next selection and so on. If the user unselects all the boxes, it will say "Nothing to show" in the table but then still show the modal, when it should only say "Nothing to show".

Hope this makes sense! I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just set a timeoutID outside of the function scope and then `clearTimeout(timeoutID)` each time the function is called. Additionally you can hold the ajaxRequest in an ID as well and call `about()` on it. Note that in addition to it being assigned the the ajax function `ajaxRequestID = $.ajax({...`, it's also being cleared out upon success `ajaxRequestID = null`

```js
let timeoutID, ajaxRequestID

function timeout() {
  if (timeoutID) clearTimeout(timeoutID); // cleat the timeout
  if (ajaxRequestID) ajaxRequestID.abort();
  // Get the modal
  $('#myModal').hide();
  $("#policyBrowserTable").empty().append("Reload pending..please select your filter(s)");
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').show()
    }, 3000);
  }
  getPolicyData(false);
}

function getPolicyData(dataLoaded) {
  var eventProfLink = '<?php echo $eventProfilesLink ;?>';
  var eventRulesLink = '<?php echo $eventProfilesRulesLink ;?>';
  var eventGroupLink = '<?php echo $eventProfilesGroupsLink ;?>';
  $("#policyBrowserTable").html("Loading policy data, this could take up to 20 seconds");
  // Only shows modal during initial page load or refresh
  if (dataLoaded) $('#myModal').show();
  let checkedArr = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    checkedArr.push($(this).parent().text());
  });
  if (checkedArr.length > 0) {
    ajaxRequestID = $.ajax({
      url: 'getPolicies.php',
      data: ({
        eventProfLink: eventProfLink,
        eventRulesLink: eventRulesLink,
        eventGroupLink: eventGroupLink,
        checkedArr: checkedArr
      }),
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        ajaxRequestID = null
        $("#policyBrowserTable").empty().append(response);
        $('#myModal').hide();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#policyBrowserTable").empty().append("Nothing to show");
    $('#myModal').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#myModal,
#policyBrowserTable {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myModal'>Modal</div>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <span id="severity">Severity:</span>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="criticalSeverityFilter" name="criticalFilter" onclick="timeout(this)" checked><span> CRITICAL</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="majorSeverityFilter" name="majorFilter" onclick="timeout(this)" checked><span> MAJOR</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="minorSeverityFilter" name="minorFilter" onclick="timeout(this)"><span> MINOR</span></label>
</div>

<div id='policyBrowserTable'></div>
```

Comment: Answer updated to accommodate the ajax cancelation as well

Comment: I updated the answer and also jQuery-ized your code. to test if there are any checkboxes checked, you can simple do: `if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {`